# How can union directories remove the need for a PATH environment variable?

Tags: operating-system, directory-structure

How can union directories remove the need for a PATH environment variable (which contains a list of directories that the shell will search for executable files)?

Comment: Please elaborate more as to what you mean by `union directories`! Are you kinda referring to **[union mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount)**

Comment: yes, i am referring to union mount

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because "_3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._"